# Bare-metal hypervisor that works with Intel Core Duo T2500 CPU?

Tags: virtualization

Is there a bare-metal hypervisor that can work with the x86 virtualization capabilities of the T2500 Core Duo  ?

(32-bit Host w/ 32-bit guests)

Before I go try a bunch of products, thought I'd give a shot asking SU if anyone has managed to get anything working..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have specific experience with T2500 Core Duo and any hypervisor, but the T2500 has Intel VT extensions. Pretty much all [modern hypervisors support Intel VT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_virtualization#Software_using_AMD-V_and.2For_Intel_VT). One free one that I have messed with (but doesn't have the correct chipset support for me) was [VMWare ESXi Server](http://www.vmware.com/products/esxi/).

Answer (score 1):

VMWare ESXi is very bare metal, it is a proprietary hypervisor managed by a "helper" Linux kernel.  However, ESXi (as far as I have seen) doesn't allow you to use the monitor/keyboard plugged into the server to use the guest OSes, meaning you would have to access the VMs from another machine.

An alternative would be to use the Linux kernel virtual machine, kvm.  With a very small Linux system (you could probably fit it in a ramdisk if you wanted) you have a hypervisor that could be called bare metal.